# JavaFX AudioClip unable to create player

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm running Linux Mint 17.1 and every time I try to play an mp3 using the AudioClip class in JavaFX I get a `com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException` saying it could not create the player. If I use Audacity to re-encode the file into a wav or aiff it works fine. The stack trace doesn't have any sections of my code listed so I'm hoping someone could tell me what I'm missing. I'm assuming it's some system library or codec or something that I'm missing that prevents mp3's from working properly.

Stack Trace as requested:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:222)
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:104)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.play(NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.java:319)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.clipScheduler(NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.java:112)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.access$000(NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.java:47)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer$Enthreaderator.lambda$static$4(NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer.java:85)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClipPlayer$Enthreaderator$$Lambda$96/875994855.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you please provide stacktrace?

Comment: Well I think internally the media validation process probably assumes that mp3's are music files. There is also the possibility that the encoded cover image if it has one is too large. Generally AudioClip is meant for system beeps, ambient noises when clicking on something etc.. I'm pretty sure you'll be able to play the mp3's using the MediaPlayer class..

Comment: @maxd I have posted the stack trace

Comment: @jdub1581 I'll give `MediaPlayer` a try instead but it wasn't saying unsupported also while it does have a cover image I re-encoded it in Audacity to MP3 again which removed the cover image.

Comment: @jdub1581 same thing happens with `MediaPlayer` works with wav re-encode but not with the original mp3 or a re-encoded mp3 just to make sure it's not something specific to the mp3 I have. It's the same error only this time it gives a problem with my code on the creation of the `MediaPlayer` object. And I'm assuming that's because the media isn't loaded by the `MediaPlayer` class like it is with `AudioClip` but instead with `Media`

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt mp3 file..

Comment: You should read up on the AudioClip in the JavaDoc.. It will load all data into memory so it has instant playback, if your mp3 is say, 3+ mins. long then it will probably hurt the app.

Comment: @jdub1581 but I can re-encode it to wav or aiff and it works fine and I can play the mp3 in an outside program and if I re-encode it into an mp3 then it also won't work and the other thing is it doesn't even play with `MediaPlayer` and isn't that designed for longer files? It also doesn't work with a freshly created 5 second mp3 giving the same error.

Comment: @jdub1581 so it plays fine on Windows because I had my friend test it so I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I'd maybe try reinstalling the jdk?

Comment: @jdub1581 that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Well it's not the code, it ran on your friends machine right?
Might be an internal bug for your os..

Comment: @jdub1581 yea it ran fine. I just don't get why I can play it fine in another program but not in mine because if it were a missing codec I don't think that's what would happen but I feel like it's something I'm missing because re-installing the JDK did no good and other formats are working.